# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/dashboard

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I am a newbie in django. I am trying to build this application where I have static "EDIT PROFILE" and "DASHBOARD" page. But when I am trying to make it dynamic I am able to create and access it (e.g http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/edit/32/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/dash/32/)

However, when I try to put this newly dynamic links into other html page for users to access it I get NoReverse Match error. I have been stuck here for last five days and tried different things. Nothing worked out. I am really getting frustrated. Please help me on fixing it. Thank you.

models.py

```
     class Profile(models.Model):
         user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
         nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True) #Don't see any use of it 
         exam_1 =models.CharField(blank= True, null = True, max_length= 20)

         def __str__(self):
              return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)
```

views.py

```
        def editt_profile(request, profile_id):
           prof_view =get_object_or_404(Profile,pk =profile_id)
           context = {
                'prof_view': prof_view,
                  }
           return render(request, 'accounts/profile_detail.html', context)

        def dash(request, profile_id):
           p_view =get_object_or_404(Profile,pk=profile_id)
           context = {
               'p_view': p_view,      
                     }
           return render(request, 'accounts/newdashboard.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
        path("edit/<int:profile_id>/", views.editt_profile, name='editt_profile'),
        path('dash/<int:profile_id>/', views.dash, name = 'dash'),
```

newdashboard.html (in this page I want to provide links to above urls for users to access)

```
        <li
          {% if 'editt_profile' in request.path %}
          class="nav-item active mr-3"
          {% else %}
          class="nav-item mr-3"
          {% endif %}
          >
         <a class="nav-link" href= "{% url 'editt_profile' prof_view.id%}">
            New Edit</a>
         </li>

         <li
           {% if 'dash' in request.path %}
           class="nav-item active mr-3"
           {% else %}
           class="nav-item mr-3"
           {% endif %}
           >
           <a class="nav-link" href= "{% url 'dash' p_view.id  %}">
             New Dashboard</a>
         </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using prof_view.id here but from where it catch the id? 
{% url 'editt_profile' prof_view.id%}">

Comment: profile_id is the primary key of the "MODEL" Profile.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when url template tag can't generate appropriate url.
if you write {% url 'edit_profile' 1 %} then it will generate url like this

```
localhost:8000/../edit/1/
```

So, if the third parameter of url tag didn't get any value, it generates url like this

```
localhost:8000/../edit/
```

and this will not match with any url. You should aware of this third parameter prof_view.id.
Did you pass prof_view key in context from where you rendering dashboard.html? or your dashboard.html getting any value for prof_view keyword? So,

change your tag

```
{% url 'editt_profile' prof_view.id%}
```

to

```
{% url 'editt_profile' p_view.id%}
```

because your context parameter is p_view, not prof_view. and in views.py change template name to 'accounts/dashboard.html'

Comment: my editt_profile function has prof_view and dash function p_view. I have two separate views function. 1. editt_profile 2. dash

Comment: from where your dashboard.html is rendering? in the dash function? but you wrote 'accounts/newdashboard.html'. you should change it to 'accounts/dashboard.html'
and in this function, your context key is p_view, so you should use p_view.id
 in template.

Comment: I edited it to newdashboard.html. Same error exist. However, In my Profile models the value starts from 7 (Id 1-6 don't exist). Can this cause problem?

Comment: no, did you change prof_view to p_view? could you provide screenshot?

Comment: I am quite confused on why I should change prof_view to p_view. in editt_profile I am trying to access db through prof_view and in dash I am doing it with p_view. Both views render different html page. (BTW, I followed your suggestion but it didn't work)

Comment: I want you to change prof_view in template, not in view. because newdashboard.html rendering from dash view and there is no prof_view context.

Comment: which view function is using for  /accounts/dashboard/ url?

Comment: for dashboard I am using def dash function. I think I have found the problem. As I don't have profile from id(1-6) in my db, this error is generated. When I specify 
 {% url 'edit_profile' 7 %} to  {% url 'edit_profile' 32 %} manually it did not give any error. 

I tried to do:  prof_view =get_object_or_404(Profile,pk =profile_id)[7:] but it shows another error. This time --"'Profile' object is not subscriptable" error. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: you got the point. No need to specify id in queryset. It will be managed automatically.
main problem is, when you calling {% url 'edit_profile' prof_view.id %} in template, no values found for prof_view.id, it returns blank all time. because id dash function your context key is context = {
               'p_view': p_view,      
                     }
so you can only access p_view.id in templete